# Is it possible to crop the background image of a div with CSS/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, image

So I got a div. That div has a background image. The background image is a world map. I need to clip this image at two precise points. Clipping the map from the left side is easy.

In CSS

```
.le-map {
  background-image: url('../img/le-map-of-le-world.mlg');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And in JavaScript

```
var clipLeft = [Number of pixels left into the image, 
from which I want to begin cropping the image] 
$leMap.css({ background-position: -(clipX)}
```

I set div to take a background image of the map, and then sprite the image so it shifts to the left by the specific number of pixels I specify.

But I also want to crop it from the right side as well, at another specific point, also to be stored in a JavaScript variable.

Is this possible?

Thx
--Gaweyne

Comment: You could look into using canvas and drawImage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage#Using_the_drawImage_method

Comment: Nuuuuuu not on the canvas. 

I used canvas to create the image. I drew some things on top of the canvas as well with paths. If I crop it there it messes it what I'm trying to do. Long story.

Comment: You could add a new class to that div with jQuery and style it with CSS to change the background.

Comment: I can already select the div in jQuery just fine. What styles would I need to add to do what I want to do? :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it. Drew the image onto the canvas and cropped it by adding extra arguments to the .drawImage() method.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to crop the image, not scale in any way, you can create some kind of parent container with `overflow:hidden` and then scale its size with JS.

Comment: Ah, that's the problem. Have to scale the image. The original size is way too big. It's a div that is produced dynamically in different places around my web application. So fixing the width of the image to explicit dimensions will also cause problems.

Comment: @Gaweyne, no mention of resizing a bigger image in your question - please add it!